# Display more than one row in tabular form while page loading in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

i have used a tablular form in a master detail page.
while opening the details page that tabular form is coming with no rows.
how can i set it to come with more than one rows.

can anyone help?

Comment: union all select ... from dual connect by level <= 5

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have to do anything. In a master-detail relationship, the detail form displays rows related to their master.

- if there are no details for a certain master, there's nothing to be displayed
- if there's one detail row for a master, you'll see one row displayed
- etc.

You can, however, *add* new rows into a detail table, by pushing the "Add row" button on the tabular form page.